# How to check the end of the loop, three-round check java

Tags: java

I am new to java and trying to build a game flow for the parsed data.

1. The game is three times per round, so if there are more scenarios in the ArrayList, the game will prompt the user to continue playing
2. If there are only three scenarios, the game ends directly without prompting the user to continue.
3. If the number of scenarios is not divided by 3. For example, 10, the game runs out of the scenarios and ends the games directly.

Any help or hint is highly appreciated. Thank you!

What I've tried like this:

```
public void interactConfig (ArrayList<Scenario> scenarios, Audit audit) throws IOException {

    ArrayList<Character> passengers = new ArrayList<Character>(); // create new reference arrayList
    ArrayList<Character> pedestrians = new ArrayList<Character>(); // otherwise, it will be all the data

    for (int i = 1; i < scenarios.size() + 1; i++) {

        Scenario s = scenarios.get(i-1);
        passengers = s.getPassengers();
        pedestrians = s.getPedestrians();
        System.out.println(s.toString());
        audit.addRun();
    
        System.out.println("Who should be saved? (passenger(s) [1] or pedestrian(s) [2])");
        String command = in.nextLine();
        
        // want to check if the game reaches the end
        // or run out of the scenarios, but failed
        if (i == scenarios.size() + 1) {
            
            decisionCalculate(command, audit, passengers, pedestrians);               
            System.out.println(audit.toString());           
            audit.printStatistic();

        }

        // three scenarios per round is perfect
        if (i != 0 && i % 3 == 0) {

            decisionCalculate(command, audit, passengers, pedestrians);
            System.out.println(audit.toString());           
            audit.printStatistic();

            System.out.println("Would you like to continue? (yes/no)");
            playAgain = in.nextLine();
            
            if (playAgain.equals("yes"))
                continue;
            else 
                break;
            
        } 
        
        // if the numbers of scenarios is not yet three times, the game keeps going
        else if (i == 0 && (i % 3) != 0) {

            decisionCalculate(command, audit, passengers, pedestrians);
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: for loop should start from 0 and till < scenarios.size() and and counter == scenarios.size() , it will out of loop and you will get to know it is end of loop.

Comment: You're testing for conditions that can never be true inside the loop: `i==scenarios.size()+1` will never be true, because the loop limits `i` to being less than `scenarios.size()+1`.  And `(i == 0 && (i % 3) != 0)` will never be true, first because `i == 0` will never be true (`for (i = 1;...`); and second, even if somehow `i==0` _were_ true, `(i % 3)` would always be zero and thus `(i %3) != 0` would always be false.

Comment: thank you all. I've figured out. I'll delete this post later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using the `i % 3 == 0`, it would show four scenarios for the first round (0, 1, 2, 3). And it's the reason why I set i starts from 1.

Therefore, to reduce complexity and increase the readability, I chose to use another variable called `numScenario` to represent the actual number of scenarios and bring back `int i = 0`. Then, it's easier to use the modulo to do the flow control.

I did like this:

```
public void interactConfig (ArrayList<Scenario> scenarios, Audit audit) throws IOException {

    ArrayList<Character> passengers = new ArrayList<Character>(); // create new reference arrayList
    ArrayList<Character> pedestrians = new ArrayList<Character>(); // otherwise, it will be all the data

    for (int i = 0; i < scenarios.size(); i++) {

        int numScenario = i + 1;

        Scenario s = scenarios.get(i);
        passengers = s.getPassengers();
        pedestrians = s.getPedestrians();
        System.out.println(s.toString());
        audit.addRun();
    
        System.out.println("Who should be saved? (passenger(s) [1] or pedestrian(s) [2])");
        String command = in.nextLine();

        // if it reaches the last round, it will be this scenario
        if (numScenario % 3 == 0 && numScenario == scenarios.size()) {
            
            decisionCalculate(command, audit, passengers, pedestrians);

        } 
        // if it's not the end the ArrayList, will be this one
        else if (numScenario % 3 == 0 && numScenario != scenarios.size()) {

            decisionCalculate(command, audit, passengers, pedestrians);

            System.out.println(audit.toString());           
            audit.printStatistic();

            System.out.println("Would you like to continue? (yes/no)");
            playAgain = in.nextLine();
            
            if (playAgain.equals("yes"))
                continue;
            else 
                break;
        }
        // other scenarios situation
        else if (numScenario % 3 != 0) {               

            decisionCalculate(command, audit, passengers, pedestrians);
            
        }
        
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you've made the logic more complicated than it needs to be.  You're trying to handle each scenario as if it belonged to exactly one of three distinct special cases:

- **Special case #1** IF it's the last scenario in the list:

  - Play the scenario
  - Print stats
- **Special case #2** IF it's every third scenario, but not last in the list:

  - Play the scenario
  - Print stats
  - Ask "Continue playing?", and break loop if user wants to stop
- **Special case #3** IF it's neither every third scenario, nor the last in the list:

  - Play the scenario

The main issue is that trying to test for each special case individually is becoming confusing and error-prone.  But additionally, you've ended up unnecessarily duplicating the "play the scenario" and "print stats" code; this leads to maintenance headaches down the road if any of that code ever needs to be changed, as you now have to remember to change it in multiple places.

But there are some opportunities here to streamline and simplify the logic, and eliminate the duplicate code.  I see it shaping up more like this:

- **Normal case** for every scenario (so no need for a special test):

  - Play the scenario
- **Special case #1** IF it's the end of a round (either because it's the third scenario of the round or because it's the last scenario):

  - Print stats
  - **Special case #1.1** IF there are more scenarios left (we *know* it's the end of a round, so no need to test for that again):

    - Ask user "Continue?"

It would look something like this in code:

```
public void interactConfig (ArrayList<Scenario> scenarios, Audit audit) throws IOException {

    ArrayList<Character> passengers = new ArrayList<Character>(); // create new reference arrayList
    ArrayList<Character> pedestrians = new ArrayList<Character>(); // otherwise, it will be all the data

    for (int i = 0; i < scenarios.size(); i++) {

        Scenario s = scenarios.get(i);
        passengers = s.getPassengers();
        pedestrians = s.getPedestrians();
        System.out.println(s.toString());
        audit.addRun();
    
        System.out.println("Who should be saved? (passenger(s) [1] or pedestrian(s) [2])");
        String command = in.nextLine();
        decisionCalculate(command, audit, passengers, pedestrians);
        if (i == scenarios.size()-1 || i%3==2)  // The round is over
            System.out.println(audit.toString());           
            audit.printStatistic();
            if (i < scenarios.size()-1)) // More scenarios: keep playing?
            {
                System.out.println("Would you like to continue? (yes/no)");
                playAgain = in.nextLine();
                if (playAgain.equalsIgnoreCase("no"))
                    break;
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

I've taken the liberty of rewriting the loop to go from `i=0` to `i<scenarios.size()`, and using `i` to index `scenarios` directly, so the test for the third scenario of a full round is now `i%3==2` (`(i+1)%3==0` would also work, if you prefer).  A long-winded justification of my choice is available upon request.

Comment: Thank you for spending some time to solve this question. Have a nice day. @Kevin